# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLTableCellElement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an exercise related to a chess game. I only must represent the chessboard with static `X` or `Y` as I have just done. However, I want to add an `onClick` for each box. The click must display me if I have clicked a black or white box and if it is free or busy. I get an exception when my `onClick` function is executed and I don't understand why. My solution is:

```
<script>
      let scacchiera = [];

      function createTable() {
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            var column = document.createElement("td");
            if ((j % 2 === 1 && i % 2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0)) {
              column.style.backgroundColor = "black";
              if (i < 3) {
                column.textContent = "X";
              }
              if (i > 4) {
                column.textContent = "O";
              }
            }
            column.addEventListener("click", function (column) {
              if (column.style.backgroundColor === "black") {
                if(column.textContent ==="X"){
                    alert("black box and X");
                }else{
                    alert("black box and Y");
                }
              } else {
                if(column.textContent ==="X"){
                    alert("white box and X");
                }else{
                    alert("white box and Y");
                }
              }
            });
            row.appendChild(column);
          }
          table.appendChild(row);
        }
        scacchiera = table;
        return scacchiera;
      }

      createTable();
      document.body.appendChild(scacchiera);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever ***event*** happens,***Event*** ***object*** gets passed to the ***listener's*** ***handler***.

In order to access the target element from event object we do `e.currentTarget`

So you are naming the parameter in handler as `column`, in order to get target element `column.currentTarget` but you should consider renaming the param to  `e` or other variable since its conflicting with already declared variables.

```
column.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
             let target=e.currentTarget
              if (target.style.backgroundColor === "black") {
                if(target.textContent ==="X"){
                    alert("black box and X");
                }else{
                    alert("black box and Y");
                }
              } else {
                if(target.textContent ==="X"){
                    alert("white box and X");
                }else{
                    alert("white box and Y");
                }
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove column as an argument to event Listener callback

```
column.addEventListener("click", function (column) { ...
```

to

```
column.addEventListener("click", function () { ...
```